# What to do when a leg is not honoring fare (not a glitch / mistake)

Tags: air-travel, tickets, cancellations, american-airlines, cathay-dragon

This isn't a case of finding a glitch in the fare system. I paid about $600 for an international fare out of LAX with 2 flights (1 stop) **through American Airline's website**. When I bought the ticket, all other flights were within $100 of what I paid for so the price was not a mistake. The first leg is operated by American Airlines while the second leg is operated by Dragonair.

After I placed the flight. I received confirmation from the first leg (American Airlines) but did not receive a confirmation from Dragonair. I have called American 3 times trying to confirm my Dragonair leg. In my first 2 calls, the representative just told me to wait for the confirmation. By the 3rd time, I was told that Dragonair changed its price and now is not honoring that leg.

As a result, my entire flight is useless because I don't have a viable connection to my final destination. Now that it is less than 24 hours to my original departure time, American is now telling me that I can pay 2X my original fare to reach my destination. Is there any recourse for me to get on my flight at the advertised price?

Comment: What country are you in? US I suppose? (Just confirming)

Comment: Can you upload a scan of your receipt/itinerary from American Airlines? (Black out identifying info and credit card.) This is so outrageous as presented, my mind spins. On such short notice, I would try calling these guys: https://www.transportation.gov/airconsumer and soon.

Comment: @J.Constantine Yes, the US.

Answer (score 7):

The [DOT enforcement policy on mistaken fares](https://cms.dot.gov/sites/dot.gov/files/docs/Mistaken_Fare_Policy_Statement_05082015.pdf)

> On April 25, 2011, the Department of Transportation issued a final rule on enhancing airline
>   passenger protections which included a provision prohibiting airlines and other sellers of air
>   transportation from increasing the price of air transportation after a purchase has occurred (the
>   post-purchase price increase prohibition). See 14 C.F.R. § 399.88. Under section 399.88, a
>   purchase occurs when the full agreed upon amount has been paid by the consumer.
>
> On June 15, 2012, the Enforcement Office issued Answers to Frequently Asked Questions about
>   the application of the post-purchase price increase rule to mistaken fares. Mistaken fares are
>   offers by an airline or other seller of air transportation to sell tickets for air transportation for a
>   fare that is *usually substantially lower* than the intended ticket price for the class of service being
>   sold.

Emphasis mine.

My interpretation: since this is not a mistake fare it falls under [14 CFR 399.88 - Prohibition on post-purchase price increase](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/399.88) and AA is on the hook to deal with Dragonair. But: IANAL and I am not even playing a lawyer on television.

Comment: You should keep reading. The rest of the page clearly states that airlines must honor mistaken fares.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That does appear to be what chx is saying and also what this particular paragraph says. Why would you need to read further?

Comment: @MichaelHampton with this ruling, DOT have muddied the waters re mistaken fares but currently they are not enforcing on those; however this issue here is not a mistaken fare; I quoted DOT policy to show this as this quote a) points out the relevant law in the non-mistake case b) defines what a mistake fare is.